# Does an 'increment bitwise shift operator' exist in C#?

Tags: c#, bitwise-operators

Say I want to increment a number by a bitwise shift, i.e.

```
1, 2, 4, 8, 16, etc
```

Is there a way to condense the `i = i << 1` below to something like increment operator (++)?

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 256; i = i << 1)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You mean something like [<<=](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayt2kcfb(v=VS.100).aspx).

See [full list of C# operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`<<=`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayt2kcfb%28VS.80%29.aspx) for this. As in `i <<= 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Both of these are same. So you can use the bottom one.

```
 --first one
 for (int i = 1; i <= 256; i = i << 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
--Second one
        for (int i = 1; i <= 256; i <<= 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are looking for the <<= operator.

So instead of: `i = i << 1`

You can write: `i <<= 1`